# MongoosePush/ mod_push MongooseIM docker run not working

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I am trying to configure mod_push for mongooseIM server. I got some success but when I run docker its giving error. I am following this doc:
https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/Push-notifications/

My command looks like this :

```
docker run -v /home/ubuntu/MongooseIM/priv:/opt/app/priv   -e PUSH_FCM_APP_KEY="AAAA5y_R5rA:APA91bGUmR7xsghMfgpudP64lt1JdJ2XBqxYLijGerdIaLI7Z4ZXqYfVRYjqKIUm6opCvEvS5H8m_KEtr9J_VRJlX9Ge7U-U5S2dasjjx0LtxQfjCSddhwxYXgR4goX8fBStIdoYikYM"   -e PUSH_HTTPS_CERTFILE="/opt/app/priv/ssl/server.pem"   -e PUSH_HTTPS_KEYFILE="/opt/app/priv/ssl/server.key"   -it --rm mongooseim/mongoose-push:latest
```

And I get error :

{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,maru,{bad_return,{{'Elixir.Maru',start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{#{'**exception**' => true,'**struct**' => 'Elixir.ArgumentError',message => <<\"could not start Cowboy adapter, the file /opt/app/priv/ssl/server.key required by SSL's :keyfile either does not exist, or the application does not have permission to access it\">>},[{'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy',fail,1,[{file,\"lib/plug/adapters/cowboy.ex\"},{line,245}]},{'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy',put_ssl_file,3,[{file,\"lib/plug/adapters/cowboy.ex\"},{line,222}]},{'Elixir.Enum','-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-',3,[{file,\"lib/enum.ex\"},{line,1755}]},{'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy',normalize_cowboy_options,2,[{file,\"lib/plug/adapters/cowboy.ex\"},{line,167}]},{'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy',args,4,[{file,\"lib/plug/adapters/cowboy.ex\"},{line,49}]},{'Elixir.Plug.Adapters.Cowboy',child_spec,4,[{file,\"lib/plug/adapters/cowboy.ex\"},{line,137}]},{'Elixir.Maru','-start/2-fun-0-',4,[{file,\"lib/maru.ex\"},{line,32}]},{'Elixir.Enum','-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-',3,[{file,\"lib/enum.ex\"},{line,1755}]}]}}}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,maru,{bad_return,{{'Elixir.Maru',start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{#{'**exception**' => true,'**struct**' => 'Elixir.ArgumentError'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue, please see this link :

https://github.com/esl/MongoosePush/issues/26